Trigger build in Teamcity on chanes into target branch of pull request
I have teamcity 2022.10 and Bitbucket server 8.12. I want to apply build trigger which is runned when target branch of pull request is changed. Now I can only apply trigger on source branch changes but not target. I need it because target branch can be changed from another pull request and it is need to check open pull request against new changes. How solve that case?
I've tried adjust vcs trigger and vcs itself. I've changed them branches specification writing
+:pull-requests/*/merge

It hasn't worked.
